# Change the permissions of a discord text channel with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would have liked to make a command that allows to modify the permissions of a particular text channel discord with discord.py. For example, disable sending messages in a specific channel.

I looked at the documentation of discord.py and I saw that there is a PermissionOverwrite class (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=app#permissionoverwrite) allowing to do some things at the level of the permissions (notably with the function update)

```py
@client.command()
async def perm(ctx):
        perms = discord.Permissions()
        ctx.channel.perms.update(send_messages=False)
```

Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'perms'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`TextChannel.set_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions):

```
@client.command()
async def perm(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Comment: apparently related according to a non-answer posted as an answer: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.set_permissions