# Is it possible to change the permissions of a specific user in discord with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a Mafia game bot for Discord on python. I am a beginner in programming and I ran into a problem. When I am creating a game, my bot [makes a category with three channels: a text channel for everyone, a voice channel for everybody, and a text channel specifically for mafia players.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQpaA.png) Then the bot gives a role with the game number to every player. The problem is that I want to make mafia chat visible only for the mafia. And I don't want to make a separate role for it since it's gonna be visible if someone will check the player's roles.

Is there a way to somehow edit permissions of a channel and make it so only a certain group of people will see the channel. [You can do that by hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEFFy.png), but I didn't manage to find a way to do it with a bot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the permissions of a discord text channel with discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300146/change-the-permissions-of-a-discord-text-channel-with-discord-py)

Comment: No, unfortunately, I need to edit permissions of users in a channel, not a role, since I can't make mafia players have their own role. (Roles are visible for everyone in the server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example showing how you're able to edit permissions for a particular user:

```py
@bot.command()
async def togglechat(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    perms = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(member)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(member, read_messages=not perms.read_messages)
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully toggled {member.name}'s view of this channel!")
```

Chances are that the member will have have the value set to `None` by default, and toggling a member's view of the channel a few times will logically look like this:

```py
>>> view = None
>>> view = not view
>>> view
True
>>> view = not view
>>> view
False
>>> view = not view
>>> view
True
```

You can also set it to be a specific value (`True`/`False`) based on what role they receive;

```py
perms.read_messages = True # or False
```

You can also use `ctx.guild.default_role` to edit `@everyone`'s view of the channel. This means that you can set their view of the channel to `False` and then edit the mafia members' view of the channel to be `True`.

---

**References:**

- [`TextChannel.set_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions)
- [`TextChannel.overwrites_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.overwrites_for)
- [`Guild.default_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.default_role)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But for some reason, I get that error when I'm trying to use what you suggested: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'PermissionOverwrite' object has no attribute 'items'. There is my code: https://i.imgur.com/0lDhlDv.png

Comment: Thank you very much, now it worked! So nice to see nice people here!