# how to lock channel automatically when a specific role is given to for example 20 people

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want my bot to lock a specific channel automatically after a role is given to some 20 people. like I have a on message event on that channel which give role to members . and I want my bot to automatically lock that channel when the role is given to 20 people

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the permissions of a discord text channel with discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300146/change-the-permissions-of-a-discord-text-channel-with-discord-py)

Comment: nope bro i want my bot to lock channel when like 20 roles are given to people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `set_permissions`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(m):
    # add role
    role = m.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    if role.members >= 20:
        await m.channel.set_permissions(m.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    await bot.process_commands(m)
```