# How to change channel permissions without having a message sent first?

Tags: discord.py

I have a program that changes what channel members can see at certain times of the day. To do this, I can either change the roles that every member has, or change the permissions of each channel. However, I have looked all over the web and all of the ways for either method require a message to be sent so that the data from that message can be read and put into the function, such as:

```
@client.command()
async def perm(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False
```

[Change the permissions of a discord text channel with discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300146/change-the-permissions-of-a-discord-text-channel-with-discord-py)

or

```
async def addrole(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.server.roles, name="Test")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

[Discord.py | add role to someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076798/discord-py-add-role-to-someone)

My current program looks like this:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
import datetime

async def live_day(schedule):
  current_place = "the void"
  while True:
    current_time = str((datetime.datetime.now() -datetime.timedelta(hours=7)).time())
    int_time = int(current_time[:2] + current_time[3:5])
    for x in range(len(schedule)):
      try:
        start_time = schedule[x][1]
        end_time = schedule[x + 1][1]
      except IndexError:
        end_time = 2400
      if current_place != schedule[x][0] and int_time >= start_time and int_time < end_time:
        current_place = schedule[x][0]
        #Change the channel permissions of the current place to allow viewing
        #Change the channel permissions of the last channel to disallow viewing


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("{0.user} has arrived for duty".format(client))
  client.loop.create_task(live_day([
    ("Home", 0), 
    ("Work", 900), 
    ("Home", 1700), 
    ("Nightclub", 2000), 
    ("Home", 2200),
    ]))


client.run(my_secret)
```

Never mind the badly written code, how would I do this or where should I go to figure this out? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I could get the channels individually by using this,

```
channel1=client.get_channel(channelid)
```

[discord.py, send message by channel id without on_message() event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321520/discord-py-send-message-by-channel-id-without-on-message-event)

but then I can't use this for more than one server. How can I get channels by name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only one channel's permissions (per guild) this might fit your needs:

```py
#changing "Home" channel visibility, every day at 5 pm.

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        five_pm = current_time.replace(hour=17, minute=0, second=0)
        if current_time == five_pm:
            for guild in client.guilds: #looping through all the guilds your bot is in
                channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="Home") #getting channel by name by using "discord.utils"
                await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, view_channel=True) #changing permissions
```

By using the `on_ready()` event you can loop through the **time check** without sending any message.

***Remember to `import discord.utils`.***

Answer (score 0):

Note on [`on_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_ready):

- This function is not guaranteed to be the first event called. Likewise, this function is not guaranteed to only be called once. This library implements reconnection logic and thus will end up calling this event whenever a RESUME request fails.
- Using this function may crash the bot.

Instead create [`background tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) and use [`wait_until_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_until_ready).

You can find examples in https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v1.7.3/examples/background_task.py